# Ruby Code RSpec fail on 6.2.5 in Ruby on Rails tutorial2nd_edition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

i have a failure with my ruby RSpec Code.
I hope you can help me with that. 
The failure is coming when I'm adding the e-mail duplicate validation.

This is my user_spec Code

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  subject {  @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
        addresses.each do |invalid_address|
            @user.email = invalid_address
            @user.should_not be_valid
        end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
        addresses.each do |valid_address|
            @user.email = valid_address
            @user.should be_valid
        end
    end
  end
  describe "when email address is already taken" do
        before do
            user_with_same_email = @user.dup
            user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
            user_with_same_email.save
        end
        it { should_not be_valid }
    end
end
```

And here is the user.rb code, which is the model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
     VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
     validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

I got this failure when I'm testing it. I have no clue what's wrong and i also didn't found a solution in the web.

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-rails (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
..[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
F......

Failures:

  1) User 
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.26438 seconds
9 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:14 # User
```

Comment: 6.2.5? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Sure, i change the title soory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more by way of further troubleshooting suggestions than an actual answer.

The key information to look for next is which validation is failing.  In an IRB console session try running

```
user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
user.valid? # we're expecting this to return false
user.errors.messages # returns the message for the validation that's failing.
```

If you know which of your validations is failing it will be much easier to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it all came up green.

My guess is that you had some exception in earlier rspec runs and consequently you have some data in your test db that's never been successfully removed.

Try

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

and see if you still have a problem.